# Does sendBeacon set cookie headers when it queues the request?

Tags: javascript, analytics

```
 function trackClickAndForward() {
         navigator.sendBeacon("https://www.example.com/tracker");
         window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/homePage";
    }
```

Another way of asking this question. Is it guaranteed that sendBeacon's analytics request to 'www.example.com/tracker' will not include any cookies that may be set on the *.example.com domain from the "www.example.com/homePage" response?

Comment: I think the response is here: https://github.com/w3c/beacon/issues/63